# onChange event does not fire with FormControl and ControlValueAccessor (angular 6)

Tags: angular, form-control, angular-ngselect

I am trying to wrap a ng-select (https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) component with a custom component, I am using ControlValueAccessor with a reactive form,

```
export class ShNgSelectComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, 
ControlValueAccessor {
   @Input() shItems: Array<object>;
   @Input() shBindValue: string;
   @Input() shBindLabel: string;
   @Input() shPlaceholder: any;

  @Output() shChange = new EventEmitter<Object>();

  ngOnInit() {  
  }


  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.shItems = value || '';
  }

  propagateChange(event){
    this.shChange.emit(event);
   }


  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
   }

  registerOnTouched() { }
}
```

here is the template for the sh-ng-select

```
<ng-select [items]='shItems' [bindValue]='shBindValue' [placeholder]='shPlaceholder' [bindLabel]='shBindLabel' (change)='propagateChange($event)'></ng-select>
```

and here is the main component where i want to embed my custom component

```
<sh-ng-select [shItems]='manufactureList' [shFormGroup]='requestForm' (shChange)='getModels($event)' formControlName="manufactureId" [shPlaceholder]='"اختر الشركة المصنعة"' [shBindValue]='"id"' [shBindLabel]='"name"'></sh-ng-select>
```

the shChange event fires normally before i add the formControlName, but once I do the event does not fire, and the console does not throw any error......why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me when you add the formControlName it bind everything it need to work,  so it will call the registerOnChange , registerOnTouched,  writeValue...  since he call the registerOnChange and do "**this.propagateChange = fn**" the propageChange method will no longer reference the one you define :

```
  propagateChange(event){
    this.shChange.emit(event);
   }
```

So the shChange event emitter is not called anymore

---

For more information, making components working with [(ngModel)] / formControlName repeat the same pattern, here you can find a simple implementation that you could extend to use in your component :
https://github.com/xrobert35/asi-ngtools/blob/master/src/components/common/default-control-value-accessor.ts

A simple component using it : https://github.com/xrobert35/asi-ngtools/blob/master/src/components/asi-checkbox/asi-checkbox.component.ts

Comment: it worked after doing the above implementation, except it throws an error: "ERROR TypeError: items.map is not a function", this is due to shItems which is passed to [items] in ng-select is transformed into a string and [items] accepts an array

Comment: When the formControl init it will call the writeValue with the default value. Here I think the default value is undefined so this.shItems = value || '';  will defined "this.shItems to ''  , you should have write : this.shItems = value || [];

Comment: it worked after removing this.shItems = value || ''; from the  writeValue() method

Comment: what have you write instead ?

Comment: I left it empty!

Comment: If you let it empty you will not be able to define the default value from the formControl so you should handle this case. Futhermore you should also manage the "disabled"   setDisabledState(disabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = disabled;
  }  which can be also set from the formControl

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180281/discussion-between-m-gamie-and-xrobert35).